# Create whole path automatically when writing to a new file

Tags: java, path, directory, filewriter

I want to write a new file with the [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html). I use it like this:

```
FileWriter newJsp = new FileWriter("C:\\user\Desktop\dir1\dir2\filename.txt");
```

Now `dir1` and `dir2` currently don't exist. I want Java to create them automatically if they aren't already there. Actually Java should set up the whole file path if not already existing.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 475, accepted):

Something like:

```
File file = new File("C:\\user\\Desktop\\dir1\\dir2\\filename.txt");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
```

Comment: Why getParentFile and not just mkdirs?

Comment: Will it override the previous folder, if I am reissuing the same code with different sibling file?

Comment: @surajs1n: If the directory already exists, `mkdirs` will do nothing.

Comment: @sauperl: If the file doesn't exist yet, _mkdirs()_ will assume everything specified is a directory and creates it as such (just tested it).
By using _getParentFile()_, you leave the creation of the file itself to the _FileWriter_.

Comment: Do we need to check if `getParentFile()` returns null, for example if the file is directly in the root directory?

Comment: @Cloud: Not for the specific code I've given, which clearly *isn't* in the root directory. As with all SO answers, you should consider your own context and how you may need to change the code.

Answer (score 173):

Since Java 1.7 you can use Files.createFile:

```
Path pathToFile = Paths.get("/home/joe/foo/bar/myFile.txt");
Files.createDirectories(pathToFile.getParent());
Files.createFile(pathToFile);
```

Comment: Important to keep in mind that relative paths might cause null pointer exception.
`Path pathToFile = Paths.get("myFile.txt");
Files.createDirectories(pathToFile.getParent());`

Comment: if(!Files.exists(pathToFile.getParent())) Files.createDirectory(pathToFile.getParent()); //Test if the dir already exists to avoid error

Comment: @AndreNel JavaDoc of `createDirectories` states: Unlike the createDirectory method, an exception is not thrown if the directory could not be created because it already exists.

Answer (score 32):

Use `File.mkdirs()`:

```
File dir = new File("C:\\user\\Desktop\\dir1\\dir2");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename.txt");
FileWriter newJsp = new FileWriter(file);
```

Answer (score 18):

Use [`File.mkdirs()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()).

Comment: That will create a _directory_ `C:\\user\Desktop\dir1\dir2\filename.txt\`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Only if you keep the filename component.

Answer (score 4):

Use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) to handle all these headaches.

Edit: For example, use below code to write to a file, this method will 'checking and creating the parent directory if it does not exist'.

```
openOutputStream(File file [, boolean append])
```

Comment: Please, could you be more specific?

Comment: Hi Jean, Edited. There is a whole bunch of other useful methods under FileUtils. Apache Commons IO classes such as OIUtils and FileUtils makes java developers' life easier.

Comment: I agree FileUtils is a good way to go, but I think an easier way to this is using writeStringToFile, not openOutputStream. E.g. File file = new File("C:/user/Desktop/dir1/dir2/filename.txt"); FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file,"foo bar baz",true);

Comment: Thanks for that . Made my code much cleaner now. Link to recent javadoc : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html