# Create Directory along with file using file stream in java

Tags: java, file

I have a String like this `"D:/Data/files/store/file.txt"` now I want to check ,is directory is already exist or not, if not I want to create directory along with text file. I have tried `mkdirs()` but its creating directory like this `data->files->store->file.txt`. means its creates `file.txt` as folder, not a file. can any one kindly help me to do this. thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html you'll find all the methods you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create whole path automatically when writing to a new file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833853/create-whole-path-automatically-when-writing-to-a-new-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run mkdirs() on parent directory, not the file itself

```
File file = new File("D:/Data/files/store/file.txt");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
try {
    file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go...

```
boolean b = (new File("D:/Data/files/store/file.txt").getParentFile()).mkdirs();
```